# "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type True/False" message

Tags: dax

I am trying to write the equivalent of a COUNTIFS formula in Excel but with DAX

This is what the formula in Excel looks like

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!$V:$V,"Y",MachineData!$E:$E,"<>*rinse*",MachineData!$C:$C,">="&$J$20-30, MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&$J$20+0.999988)
```

and this is what I am trying to do with DAX

```
Completed 1 Month = COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData,
MachineData[Successful Run?] = "Y" &&
MachineData[Type] <> CONTAINSSTRING(MachineData[Type], "rinse") &&
DATESBETWEEN(MachineData[StartTime], MAX(MachineData[StartTime]) - 30, MAX(MachineData[StartTime]))))
```

Basically what I am trying to do is
Count if

- Successful Run? has a "Y" on it
- Type does not contain the word "rinse" on it
- Filter by the data selected in the slicer, and 30 days back.

When I try to display this value in a card, it gives me an error message of "DAX comparison opearations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type True/False."

The StartTime field is recognized as a date on PowerBI, and the other fields are text, so not sure why it is saying I am trying to compare values of different types.

Edit: the Analysis Complete? column has some rows that are empty, could this be causing the error?

Comment: I think that `Successful Run?` is boolean ie `True/False` in power BI, to check that select your column and see in ribbons Data type. in addition, to filter by the last 30 days you need to ignore date filter, to do that by using `All`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your CONTAINSSTRING is returning TRUE/FALSE, So it has to be compared with TURE/FALSE only. Hence you were getting an error. Below Measure is a correct version of it.

```
Completed 1 Month = COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData,
MachineData[Successful Run?] = "Y" &&
CONTAINSSTRING(MachineData[Type], "rinse")=FALSE() &&
DATESBETWEEN(MachineData[StartTime], MAX(MachineData[StartTime]) - 30, MAX(MachineData[StartTime]))))
```